# IEnumerable<T> unknown type preserve class information

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to write an attribute filter that takes an `IEnumerable<anything>` and calls skip and take on it.

In the OnActionExecuted I get an object that I can cast to `IEnumerabe<object>` and call skip and take on (perfect), works well.

Problem is skip and take seem to go, well I was cast as `IEnumerable<object>` so I will return an `IEnumerable<object>` completely wiping out what the type information was.

This is fine in most cases, however I wanted to use multiple attributes and have them inspect the type information to get say object names out, the type information in the second action filter has become object.

Basically is there anyway to have

```
var list = new List<string>{"a","b","c"};

var objectlist = list as IEnumerable<object>;    
var newenumerable = objectlist.Take(10);

newenumerableastype = newenumerable as IEnumerable<string>
Assert.IsNotNull(newenumerableastype); //Currently this will be null as newenuerable is IEnumerable<object>
```

There doesn't appear to be any facility to force the typing of the IEnumerable from a variable (I could get this before the LINQ queries, but without the ability to cast/convert it... its pointless).

EDIT:

I will try an make it a tad more clearer, I'm trying to plug into the WebAPI2 actionfilters, these basically give me quite literally an 'object' that was the return type on a controller. I can use reflection to get that it is an IEnumerable, even getting out the type `<T>` by examining the kind of enumerable.

The problem is there is no way to treat that 'object' as something of it's type, but I don't care about the actual type T other than to get its type information.

The C# extension methods for Take and Skip seem to create a new sort of IEnumerable that is a subset of the previous one, this is what I wanted, problem is they remove the type information in the process.

```
(IEnumerable<object> variable).Take(10) // returns an IEnumerable<object>
```

I would very much like my methods to 1) not have to predefine the types (adding generics to attributes would work, but not supported by the language) or 2) allow the extension methods to return `IEnumerable<T>` based on what the `IEnumerable<T>` was constructed with, not what it was cast as.

UPDATE:

So in the real world of 'making' things work, I discovered I am able to use a different property on the ActionFilter executedContext, this seems to have the original type information (even if I mess with the IEnumerable), so successive things in the filter 'chain' can get the type information.

Still it's an interesting problem, I would be curious if I could somehow call take on an enumerable and have the type information preserved (as an aside its odd how take is defined on `IEnumerable<T>`, shouldn't it really just exist on IEnumerable?, what about Take needs to know what the object type is? it just needs to return X of them).

Academically still curious if there is a way around this in the language though :)

Comment: Why do you need to use `object` at all?

Comment: Thats what the ActionFilterAttribute seems to pass in. I get a HttpActionExecutedContext. And my research has shown you cannot write attributes that have generic<T> types.

Comment: Ah apologies I must have overlooked that part of your question

Comment: Any time you use < > in a post you must surround it with backticks ` Otherwise the site thinks you are posting HTML tags and will strip them out. See the parts I updated (I did not look carefully, there could be more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There doesn't appear to be any facility to force the typing of the
>   IEnumerable from a variable.

This is true, because the typing of the IEnumerable is a compile time thing and the type of the variable is a runtime thing.  If you know that all the types of each object within the IEnumerable as the same then you could do:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"a","b","c"};

IEnumerable<object> objectlist = list as IEnumerable<object>;    
IEnumerable<object> newenumerable = objectlist.Take(10);


Type listTypeOf = newenumerable.FirstOrDefault().GetType();
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(listTypeOf);
dynamic dynamicList = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
foreach (var item in newenumerable)
{
     dynamicList.Add((dynamic) item);
}

IEnumerable<string> newenumerableastype = dynamicList as IEnumerable<string>;

Assert.IsNotNull(newenumerableastype);
```

In this example case, this will work.  The type of dynamicList is, at runtime in this example, `List<string>`.  However, if the initial list of objects is of mixed types then you are opening yourself to some dynamic resolution errors.  For example if you change the first line of code to

```
List<object> list = new List<object>{"one", 2, 3.0};
```

then you will get a `RuntimeBinderException`, trying to add an integer to a list of strings.  Which is why your initial problem exists.  You cannot safely cast a `IEnumerable<object>` to `IEnumerable<string>` without knowing all the types of the individual elements.

Just to be clear, you can determine the types of all the things within the example, you just don't know the types at compile time.  As you have identified Take lazily creates a new IEnumerable with the same type as the source type (this being determined at compile time).  C# rules about variance try to reduce runtime errors by being strict at compile time.  You can use lazy evaluation and leave the processing of the specific types right up to the end of your LINQ pipelines and process individual elements on a type by type basis, but that would be looking at runtime rather than compile time types.

Comment: I would use `var` instead of `dynamic`.

Comment: If you use var instead of dynamic at some point you are going to have to give the compiler hints in the code of the types of the original collection, due to the static typing of C#.  My understanding of the question (although I may be wrong) is that you know the collection is of a predefined type, and that is a type you know at runtime.  However, the compiler is only aware of the collection as a collection of object and you are trying to make a more specific collection and are prevented from the type variance rules.

Comment: Issue here is that I'm wanting to just manipulate IEnumerables and allow whatever the implementation is to take care of managing the lists. Eg if its a lazy loaded EF model, I wouldn't want to serialize it out to early. (Granted I'm making the assumption that chaining LINQ elements functions similarly to AREL in rails land).

Comment: Added a last paragraph which was going to be a comment but was too long.

Comment: This solution works great for `IEnumerables` of object types (e.g., `IEnumerable<string>`), but not for value types (e.g. `IEnumerable<int>`).  It fails on the cast using `as IEnumerable<object>`.  I would love a solution that works in this case as well (and doesn't involve detecting and handling each value type explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Cast<>()` method.

```
var newCollection = newenumerable.Cast<string>()
```

*See msdn for more info: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx_)*

And if there are different types on that object collection, you can use:

```
var newCollection = newenumerable.OfType<string>()
```

---

Getting the type from a generic collection:

```
IEnumerable<object> myCollection = new List<string>();
var genericTypeArgument = myCollection.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: At best I have the type as a variable, in my tests I could probably use cast. But in the next filter I don't know the type of the objects (nor do I care), I really just want the type name.

Comment: @user1570690 Why don't you make your method have a generic `<T>`?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen if you call take on myCollection, then try to get the generic type argument that way, you get Object back, not string. Thats basically my entire issue :).

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
var newenumerable = objectlist.Cast<string>().AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` is completely redundant here